# Can a buckyball gun be fired by observing it?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, molecules

If a buckyball was placed inside a gun made from maybe a carbon nanotube or something, would measuring the momentum of the buckyball cause the the gun to fire?
At what speed would the buckyball exit the barrel if it fires? or is there just as much chance it will exit through the walls?

(Could the observation be used as the propellant?)

Comment: Could one build a highly sensitive trigger? Of course. I can couple a PMT to a large artillery piece and fire a large projective with a single photon. Having said that... what's the application?

Comment: I meant would the observation become the propellant?

Comment: Absolutely. SLAC (https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/), for instance, has a very high power pulsed x-ray facility for the observations of molecular structures and dynamics. It is so high powered that after the measurement the molecules don't exist anymore.

Comment: Ok but is that from the photon's energy or from the uncertainty in position or momentum?

Comment: Every experiment has to supply some form of energy to the sample unless that energy is already in the sample, say in the case of radioactive decay. Take the most simple case of a very precise position measurement with a "de Broglie box". According to the uncertainty relation this will increase the momentum uncertainty of the stuff in the box and by means of energy conservation we can predict that it will take that much energy to put whatever we want to measure in there and to close the lid. In this case the energy would come from the experiment, itself.

Comment: @CuriousOne  I have the feeling this might be related to the double slit experiment, I may be wrong and apologies to the OP if I am

Comment: I like to avoid the double slit experiment. I think that a closed box with quantum mechanical content (I tend to call that a "de Broglie box") is the much better system to learn about these things. It's also much easier to do calculations on it and it has fewer "moving parts".

Comment: That doesn't sound very spooky, it sounds kind of classical. What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is that one can create any amount and any type of matter with a de Broglie box. The smaller you make it, the more stuff will come out. I don't think the double slit can do that (at least not without it being fed by an accelerator). :-)

Comment: I'll read up on de Broglie boxes. Be careful about using the words "any type of matter" it inspires questions about dark matter;-)

Comment: The answer will be obvious: There is no obvious reason why dark matter, if it exists, can't be created from the energy necessary to confine a small element of space. LHC is testing that as we speak (probably without much success, though).